# umask OR chmod in multithreaded application

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, chmod, umask

Which of these is the best practice:

1. Set umask and create files with appropriate file permissions
   OR
2. Create files and then use chmod() to set appropriate file permissions

if we use umask in a thread, does it affect files created in other threads?

I know chmod affects only the file, but is likely to fail, if the files are created by a different user.

Comment: Don't meddle with the umask. Instead just use [`open` or `creat`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) passing the permissions you want, and then let the system handle it with the users umask. If you later need a standard C `FILE*`, use [`fdopen`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fdopen.3p.html).

Comment: "*if we use umask in a thread, does it affect files created in other threads?*" From [the docs](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/umask.2.html): "*`umask()` sets the calling process's file mode creation mask ...*" So yes, it affects **all** threads of a process.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Can i create files with the required permissions, wont it masked by the umask bits?

Comment: The user might have set the umask for a reason. Don't meddle with it.